# Changing to protected mode causes triple fault

Tags: assembly, x86, protected-mode

I have been having an issue whereby after long jumping to protected mode, seemingly when setting up the `ss` register, a triple fault is caused. My code:

`switch-to-32bit.asm`

```
[org 0x7c00]
[bits 16]
switch_to_32bit:
    cli
    lgdt [gdt_descriptor]
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 0x1 ; protected mode
    mov cr0, eax
    jmp CODE_SEG:init_32bit ; far jump

[bits 32]
init_32bit:
    mov ax, DATA_SEG ; 0x1000
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    mov ebp, 0x90000 ; setup stack
    mov esp, ebp

    call BEGIN_32BIT
```

`gdt.asm`

```
gdt_start:
    dq 0x0

gdt_code:
    dw 0xffff ; segment length
    dw 0x0 ; segment base
    db 0x0 ; segment base
    db 10011010b ; flags 
    db 11001111b ; flags
    db 0x0 ; segment base

gdt_data:
    dw 0xffff ; segment length
    dw 0x0 ; segment base
    db 0x0 ; segment base
    db 10011010b ; flags 
    db 11001111b ; flags
    db 0x0 ; segment base

gdt_end:

gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1
    dd gdt_start

CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start
DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start
```

When running this with `bochs`, a lot of debugging lines come into the console, as seen here:
[image: Debug log]

Does anyone know why setting the `ss` register causes this issue? Or maybe if the issue is deeper (I see `SS.mode = 16 bit`)? Thanks.

Comment: The code as shown loads `SS` with zero. That obviously does not work. Do you get a crash if you load it with `DATA_SEG` instead (as per the commented out code)?

Comment: Whoops I should've removed that, it was just me trying to debug the issue and was not intended.

Comment: Also update the bochs screenshot as that is still showing loading a null selector into `SS`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an incorrect flag on your data segment descriptor: `10011010b` should be `10010010b`. Bit 3 should be `0` to indicate a data segment.

When you `mov` a value into a segment register, it checks it for validity. It's valid (though not desirable) to move a (readable) code segment descriptor into `DS`, as long as you don't try to write to the segment. It's not, however, valid to move that descriptor into `SS`, so that's the instruction that's faulting. You're probably getting a `#GP(0x10)` exception, which is cascading into a triple fault.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, can't believe I missed this!